# Avoid connection to facebook application after loggin

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, popup

I have a facebook-loggin button my page :

```
<div id="signin"><div id="fb-root"></div><a id="fb-login" onclick="facebookLogin()">Login with Facebook</a></div>

function facebookLogin() {
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        window.location.reload(); //or do whatever you want
    } else {
        //do smthg else
    }
});
```

}

I click on the link, a login popup appears and I proceed. After I do that, I am always asked to connect to the application that correspond to the URL of my page.

Is there a way to close the login popup after I'm logged and don't ask to connect to the application ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Read your question once again and *honestly* say - do you really think you've provided enough information?

Comment: Sorry zerkms, is it better now ?

Comment: if you're logged in - why do you show the button at all?

Comment: No, I'm working on the case where I'm not logged in. The user arrives on my site and is not connected to facebook.

Comment: so he clicks fb login button, accepts the connection to your app. What happens next?

Comment: I don't want him to accept the connection to my app. After he logs in I just would like a page reload.

Comment: Could it have something to see with the FB.init({ parameters ?